# WebDriver getText() Method with replace using Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Html Code

```
<span data-bind="html: TotalCharges">
<span class="CurrencySymbol">USD </span>
7400.00
<br>
(0.00+0.00)
</span>
```

Webdriver to get the Totalcharge value using getText method

Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-bind='html: TotalCharges']")).getText().substring(4);
```

with above will get the below output
"7400.00
(0.00+0.00)"

my Expected output :"7400.00"

so how can i replace the char from "< br>" tag (need to replace "(0.00+0.00)")
i'm using java

Comment: Your input HTML does not match the output, because the numbers are different . Please edit the question.

Comment: Can you be sure that there is always the same string `(0.00+0.00)` after the desired value? I mean, can we hardcode it in the code and replace?

Comment: @alecxe:yes the String was common with same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following xpath to get 7400.00:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='CurrencySymbol']/following-sibling::text()[1]").getText();
```

Oh My mistake, Thanks for correcting me @alecxe:
You can get it by:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='CurrencySymbol']/.."))
        .getText().split("\n")[0].split(" ")[1]
```

splitting at `\n` will split it for `<br>` tag.

Comment: Would not work, the xpath should point to an actual element - not the text node.

Comment: @Prabu if it helped can u please mark it so that others can too benefit of it...thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution. It will give you 7400.00 output-

```
String temp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html>body>span")).getText();
String s1=temp.replace("USD", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
String finalStr = s1.substring(0,s1.indexOf("(")).trim();
System.out.println(finalStr);
```